# How to make functions appear purple

Tags: function, python-3.5, python-idle

So from just learning how to make functions, I thought of if I could turn the function purple, just like a normal `print()` or `str()` function. And with that in mind, it may seem pretty obvious that I am still a beginner when it comes to coding. From what I know, it may have something to do with `sys.stdin.write`, but I don't know. This will help me to make different languages for others who don't speak or write English.

Comment: Does this answer work for you?

Comment: Please take a look at updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Options => Configure IDLE => Settings => Highlights there is a highlight setting for builtin names (default purple), including a few non-functions like `Ellipsis`.  There is another setting for the names in def (function) and class statements (default blue).  You can make def (and class) names be purple also.

This will not make function names purple when used because the colorizer does not know what the name will be bound to when the code is run.

Comment: So you're saying that it is impossible?

Comment: It is effectively impossible for a user who is not prepared to patch IDLE.  I am thinking about whether it would be possible to enhance the colorizer to recognize and color function and class names defined earlier in the file.

Answer (score 0):

### Colors for Python

Use Atom and use this theme: https://atom.io/themes/darkpython-syntax

There are more themes here: https://atom.io/themes/search?utf8=✓&q=keyword:python

You can install Atom from: https://atom.io

Comment: No, because that is to make words that print to the shell appear a certain colour. My question was a bit vague, but I wanted to have help to find out how to make my own functions appear purple like the functions that idle has. E.g print("..") the print function appears purple. However my own functions appear black.

Also you don't need colorama, you can use: 
import sys

try: color = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError: raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")) and the colors are: ERROR, hit, console, BUILTIN, SYNC, STRING, COMMENT,stdout,stderr,DEFINITION,KEYWORD. Case Sensitive.

Comment: Still no, Because that is changing all the colours of the window. I can do that really easily via options-->configure idle. Still not the right thing, also Terry Jan Reedy said that to do what I want I would need to repatch IDLE. Which I don't know how to do nor do I want to do for that small aesthetic.